# Firebase Auth: How to get User phone number/currentUser in redirected page using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't know how possible what i am trying to do is or if there is a better approach to it. I have integrated the firebase phone number authentication in my system and it works Ok but i want it just for verifying a user's phone number after which it will redirect the user the the main signup page where the user will enter other details that will be saved in my database. I am using the firebaseUi which renders the Ui in a div

```
<h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
<div id="loader"></div>
```

How do i get the verified number/currentUser to display on the redirected page. 
I have tried this from the [Manage User doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

and to get it in my redirected page i have this in my controller

```
$this['authUser'] = Request::get('user');
```

Then in twig i have 
`{{ authUser }}` but it is returning null when i dial and dump

Comment: Can you provide your html and controller code you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this solved it

Adding this to the js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      initApp = function() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            var displayName = user.displayName;
            var email = user.email;
            var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
            var photoURL = user.photoURL;
            var uid = user.uid;
            var phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
            var providerData = user.providerData;
            user.getIdToken().then(function(accessToken) {
              document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed in';
              document.getElementById('sign-in').textContent = 'Sign out';

              document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify({
                displayName: displayName,
                email: email,
                emailVerified: emailVerified,
                phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                photoURL: photoURL,
                uid: uid,
                accessToken: accessToken,
                providerData: providerData
              }, null, '  ');
            });
          } else {
            // User is signed out.
            document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed out';
            document.getElementById('sign-in').textContent = 'Sign in';
            document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = 'null';
          }
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      };

      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        initApp();
      });

    </script>
```

Then on the page

```
<div  id="sign-in-status"></div>
    <div  id="sign-in"></div>
    <pre  id="account-details"></pre>
```